# Xcode default Core Data project template has empty List and no Button to add items

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

With Xcode 12.5 (for iOS 14.5) I create a new iOS project and set the "Core Data" checkbox:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

As you can see in the above screenshot the List in the preview Canvas is filled.

But when I run the project in Simulator or at the real iPhone 11, then the List is empty (which is to be expected) and there is no "Edit" or "Add Item" button displayed, to add any new items.

I have not modified [the project](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/FetchJsonEscapable) except trying other colors (to make sure that the missing button is not black on black). Also I tried adding a List with hardcoded array of strings and it worked:

[image: iphone screenshot]

Here is my [ContentView.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/FetchJsonEscapable/FetchJsonEscapable), why there is no Button for adding or editing items displayed?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    private var items2:[String] = (1...200).map { number in "Item \(number)" }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("FetchJsonEscapable").foregroundColor(.orange)
            List {
                ForEach(items2, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("Item  \(item)")
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
/*
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
 */
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()

                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
```

**UPDATE:**

I have followed the advice by Scott (thanks!) and added [NavigationView](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/FetchJsonEscapable/FetchJsonEscapable).

Now the "Edit" button is visible, but there is still no way to add new items:

[image: emulator screenshot]

Comment: You need a NavigationView at the top. Apple’s code doesn’t come with it but to see the toolbar you need it. Put it above the VStack

Comment: I have [added the NavigationView](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/FetchJsonEscapable/FetchJsonEscapable), but the "Add items" button is still not displayed, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When toolbar items are expected to be added to the top of an iOS view, they won't appear unless the current view is part of a `NavigationView` hierarchy.

If you were to add a `NavigationView` to your `ContentView`'s body you would find the buttons appear:

```swift
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    // rest of the body
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, so do you think it is a bug in Xcode project temmplate?

Comment: I have [added the NavigationView](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/FetchJsonEscapable/FetchJsonEscapable), but the "Add items" button is still not displayed, please see my updated question.

Comment: Oh, the other thing you may need to do is wrap each button in a `ToolbarItem` with a different `placement` value, e.g.: `ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) { EditButton() }`